# How to ignore a folder in a folder on GitHub?

Tags: git, gitignore

In my project I have a folder where inside it there's another folder (and some other files I want to push), called `__pycache__`. How do I ignore the `__pycache__` folder but not the files inside the folder that contains the `__pycache__` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add this to your .gitignore file

```
parentFolder/__pycache__/
```